# Android CursorAdapter drawing things in the wrong list item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I’ve got a `CursorAdapter` that's built from a database `Cursor` and if a `View` in the first item isn't filled in, it populates the first item's `View`s with whatever data appears in that `View` in the first subsequent list item where the `View` was set.  In addition, I find that `onBindView` gets triggered three times for each list item, which seems odd.  and it only does this for the first list item, not all the items with null `View`s.  Here’s what it looks like:

[image: example]

Note that the address of "Julian" got copied to "Alice".  whenever I set a break point in the onBindView method, I can see that when the customerName is "Alice Martin", `if(billingAddressCursor!=null && billingAddressCursor.getCount()>0)` always evaluates to false for all three calls to `onBindView`, so I know it never goes into the billing conditional.

Why is it drawing the wrong values in the first position and how can I stop it?  code:

```
private class CustomerAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    /*** DEBUG CODE, TO BE REMOVED ***/
    int aliceBindCount = 0;
    int blakeBindCount = 0;
    int cscBindCount = 0;
    int julianBindCount = 0;
    /*** ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ***/
    public CustomerAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor);
    }

    public void bindView(View convertView, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        if(convertView!=null) {
            String customerName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerSchema.NAME));
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cli_customer_name)).setText(customerName);
            /*** DEBUG CODE, TO BE REMOVED ***/
            if(customerName.equals("Alice Martin")) {
                aliceBindCount += 1;
            } else if(customerName.equals("Blake Slappey")) {
                blakeBindCount += 1;
            } else if(customerName.equals("Conceptual Systems")) {
                cscBindCount += 1;
            } else if(customerName.equals("Julian")) {
                julianBindCount += 1;
            }
            /*** ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ***/
        }
        final Long billingAddressID = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerSchema.BILLING_ADDRESS_ID));
        Cursor billingAddressCursor = DbDesc.getInstance().getDatabase(getActivity()).query(
                LocationSchema.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                LocationSchema._ID+"=?",
                new String[]{ String.valueOf(billingAddressID) },
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        if(billingAddressCursor!=null && billingAddressCursor.getCount()>0) {
            billingAddressCursor.moveToFirst();
            String street = billingAddressCursor.getString(billingAddressCursor.getColumnIndex(LocationSchema.STREET));
            String city = billingAddressCursor.getString(billingAddressCursor.getColumnIndex(LocationSchema.CITY));
            String state = billingAddressCursor.getString(billingAddressCursor.getColumnIndex(LocationSchema.STATE));
            String zip = billingAddressCursor.getString(billingAddressCursor.getColumnIndex(LocationSchema.ZIP));
            if(zip==null || zip.equals("")) {
                zip = "[NO ZIP]";
            }
            if(street==null || street.equals("")) {
                street = "[NO STREET]";
            }
            if(city==null || city.equals("")) {
                city = "[NO CITY]";
            }
            if(state==null || state.equals("")) {
                state = "[NO STATE]";
            }
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cli_street)).setText(street);
            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cli_city_state_zip)).setText(city+", "+state+" "+zip);
        }
    }

    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_list_item, parent, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

And I am certain that Alice should not have a billing address associated with that record.  Here is the table query from sqlite3.  The only record with a billing address id is Julian's record, as you can see:

```
sqlite> .tables
.tables
android_metadata  contract          location
contact           customer          phone
sqlite> select * from customer;
select * from customer;
2|Conceptual Systems|||||||
3|Blake Slappey|||||||
4|Julian|1||||||
5|Alice Martin|||||||
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous and I don't think anyone understood what exactly is the problem so try to better explain the problem. Some thing that I can tell you is: `convertView` can't be `null` so that check is useless, also the `bindView` is called for each row in the `ListView` and you shouldn't querying a database in there.

Comment: the problem was actually pretty clear.  i even included pictures and all relevant code.  furthermore, there are no database transactions occurring in the adapter (which you would know if you had looked at the code i posted).  the only correct part of your comment was about convertView being null.  so thanks for that.  i can happily delete two lines of code.  losing that conditional will help speed up my application greatly.

Comment: I think you are getting a null at  final Long billingAddressID for other records, at `final Long billingAddressID = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerSchema.BILLING_ADDRESS_ID));` . and the string `String.valueOf(billingAddressID)` throws an error . This is on first look.  Let me try this out and I can get back if its not been answered already. But @stuckless below is right about the design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListView` recycles its row views, so old values that aren't explicitly set will hang around in subsequent uses.  In your code, if the query inside your binder doesn't return any rows, the values in the view from its previous use will remain.  Not what you want.

Here is a re-coding that should fix the problem:

```
   String street = "[NO STREET]";
   String city = "[NO CITY]";
   String state = "[NO STATE]";
   String zip = "[NO ZIP]";
   if(billingAddressCursor!=null && billingAddressCursor.getCount()>0) {
        billingAddressCursor.moveToFirst();
        String tmp = billingAddressCursor.getString(billingAddressCursor.getColumnIndex(LocationSchema.STREET));
        if (tmp != null) street = tmp;
        tmp = billingAddressCursor.getString(billingAddressCursor.getColumnIndex(LocationSchema.CITY));
        if (tmp != null) city = tmp;
        tmp = billingAddressCursor.getString(billingAddressCursor.getColumnIndex(LocationSchema.STATE));
        if (tmp != null) state = tmp;
        tmp = billingAddressCursor.getString(billingAddressCursor.getColumnIndex(LocationSchema.ZIP));
        if (tmp != null) zip = tmp;

    }
    ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cli_street)).setText(street);
    ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cli_city_state_zip)).setText(city+", "+state+" "+zip);
```

Having said that, this is not the right way to fill this list. One DB query per list item is going to produce a performance dog. The simplest fix is to use a single `INNER JOIN` to retrieve all the information from both tables in one query. It's still possible the query will take too long if run on the UI thread.  The preferred fix is to use the background  `Loader` capability Android to do it without tying up the UI thread.

Answer (score 5):

From looking at the code (which was a little confusing at first), it seems that you have a Custom `CursorAdapter` for `customer` and inside the `bindView()` of that adapter, you are doing a secondary query for the `location` of that person (ie, a Join from `customer` to `location`).  This is going to perform badly, given that on the UI thread, for each customer, you are doing a secondary query.

Could this be solved more easily using the [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) and a join query between `customer` and `location`.  (It seems to me the only purpose of the custom adapter is do "joining" of the `customer` and `location`, in a very inefficient way)

This way, the query would happen in the backgound, using `Loaders` perhaps, and the binding would be fairly efficient, never needing to do an alternate query.

The initial query may be something like..

```
select customer.name, location.address1, location.address2 from customer, location where customer.location_id = location._id
```

(I'm not sure what your field names are but, hopefully that conveys the basic structure)